# Get polymorphic model with spring boot, mongodb and kotlin

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, serialization, polymorphism, deserialization

I am saving a polymorphic model using mongoDB, and the data is saved perfectly, for example.

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY, property = "type", visible = true)
@JsonSubTypes(
    JsonSubTypes.Type(value = B::class, name = "test_a"),
    JsonSubTypes.Type(value = C::class, name = "test_b")
)

data class Base(
    val list:List<A>? = null
)

open class A(
    val type: String? = null
)

data class B : A(
    val value: String? = null
)

data class C : A(
    val values: List<String>? = null
)
```

the data is reflected in the database as follows

```
{
    "list":[
        {
            "type": "type a",
            "value": "test"
        },
        {
            "type": "type b",
            "values": [
                "test 1",
                "test 2"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

but when i try to get the data from mongo db it returns it but without the attributes of child classes B and C.

```
{
    "list":[
        {
            "type": "type a"
        },
        {
            "type": "type b"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am getting the data using mongoRepository with this annotation.

```
@Query("{'id' : ?0 }")
fun findById(@Param("id") id: String): Base?
```

Do you know what could be happening?

Comment: Same problem here. Obviously the deserializer is casting all entries to A because it doesn't know better, and then ignores properties not in A, while the serializer has the necessary type information and writes them into the table. A problem on the Spring side, not the database side. Some googling suggests that the JsonTypeInfo and related annotations are not working properly. You might have a typo in your sample code, but I couldn't make my code work, either.